# Loop through keys of an array, in order

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

is that easily possible?

I have the next code:

```
for each_key in "${!myArray[@]}"
    do
        echo $each_key" : "${myArray[$each_key]}
    done
```

sure it works flawesly, but items do not show in order

I try with

```
IFS=$'\n' orderedMyArray=($(sort <<< "${myArray[@]}"))
declare -p orderedMyArray
```

but is giving me values and not keys

Comment: It's not possible, associative array entries are inherently unordered. So you'll have to sort them yourself.

Comment: `$each_key" : "${myArray[$each_key]}` That's strange quoting. Just quote it - `"$each_key : ${myArray[$each_key]}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it works flawesly, but items do not show in order

Sure and ordering them on keys is trivial - just actually sort on the keys.

```
for each_key in "${!myArray[@]}"; do
    echo "$each_key : ${myArray[$each_key]}" # remember to quote variable expansions!
done | sort
```

You could sort keys before passing them to `for`:

```
for each_key in "$(printf "%s\n" "${!myArray[@]}" | sort)"; do
# or funnier:
for each_key in $(IFS=$'\n'; sort <<<"${!myArray[*]}"); do
# or I think I would do a while read:
keys=$(IFS=$'\n'; sort <<<"${!myArray[*]}")
while IFS= read -r each_key; do ...; done <<<"$keys"
```

Comment: Unless by order he meant something other than alphabetic sort. I assume you're correct, but it's easy enough either way. :)

Comment: thanks a lot !!!, great, I will go for the second options, as it is the nearest to the code

Comment: not sure why you "would do" while over for-each-in-do ??

Comment: neither why you recomend to quote the variable expresions  [yes, i am nob into bash]

Comment: `why you "would do" while over for-each-in-do ??`  `for i in $(...)` is an antipattern. Read [how to read a stream line by line in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). `why you recommend to quote the variable expressions` To prevent word splitting expansion and filename expansion. As a rule, when you see `$` it should be inside `"`. [quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something other than sorting the keys themselves in alphabetic order, you could try a parallel array.

```
$: order=( peach pear lemon lime ) # declare the order you want
$: declare -A data=( [peach]=pickled [pear]=salad [lemon]=drop [lime]=twist )
$: for k in "${order[@]}"; do echo "$k: ${data[$k]}"; done
peach: pickled
pear: salad
lemon: drop
lime: twist
```